# Is context-driven testing suitable for all projects?

Tags: testing, theory

One thing I cannot find anywhere is: is this approach limited to non-critical software? Because in critical (or just when customer wants us to follow his rules) we have no freedom in testing and just follow the procedures.
Am I right?

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question yesterday?

Comment: Yes but it was more questions in one and not that clear. I deleted that one because of that. Obviously it is not that easy as there are no answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "freedom."

Testing isn't necessarily about "freedom." Testing is about finding out if the software does what it is supposed to do.  In most "contexts," that means determining if the software meets the customer's requirements.  So any testing that occurs will be "driven" by that goal, and any testing that doesn't advance that goal is a waste of time.  This is true regardless of the testing methodology used.

In some testing methodologies like TDD, the tests themselves are part of the requirements.  Each test identifies a requirement, and the passing of that test verifies that the requirement  is fulfilled.

So let's look specifically at [some of the things that Context-Driven Testing advocates](http://context-driven-testing.com/):

1. Testing is done on behalf of stakeholders in the service of developing, qualifying, debugging, investigating, or selling a product.
2. Test artifacts are worthwhile [only] to the degree that they satisfy their stakeholders’ relevant requirements.
3. The value of any [testing] practice depends on its context.

> #### Consider two projects:
>
> - One is developing the control software for an airplane. What “correct
>   behavior” means is a highly technical and mathematical subject. FAA
>   regulations must be followed. Anything you do — or don’t do — would be
>   evidence in a lawsuit 20 years from now. The development staff share
>   an engineering culture that values caution, precision, repeatability,
>   and double-checking everyone’s work.
> - Another project is developing a word processor that is to be used over
>   the web. “Correct behavior” is whatever woos a vast and inarticulate
>   audience of Microsoft Word users over to your software. There are no
>   regulatory requirements that matter (other than those governing public
>   stock offerings). Time to market matters — 20 months from now, it will
>   all be over, for good or ill. The development staff decidedly do not
>   come from an engineering culture, and attempts to talk in a way normal
>   for the first culture will cause them to refer to you as “damage to be
>   routed around”.
>
> *Testing practices appropriate to the first project will fail in the
> second.*
>
> *Practices appropriate to the second project would be criminally
> negligent in the first.*

As you can see, Context-Driven Testing adapts itself to the project, not the other way around.  But this should really come as no surprise, since all software testing is (or should be) about proving that customer expectations are met, not about conforming oneself to some arbitrary methodology just because.

Context-Driven Testing is less about a methodology, and more about some guidelines and principles that drive all of testing.  It basically says that your testing methodologies, your rigor, your testing culture, are all based on the nature, character and culture of the software project and its participants.

In that sense, consider it the "freedom" philosophy.  You are free to adapt your testing methods to best fit the needs of the software project under test.

Comment: Well, how can you choose techniques, delirevables, methods (ie what context driven mentiones) etc. in project where everything is given and you just have to follow?

Comment: If context-driven testing is about handing a project to a testing team and allowing that team to come up with their own methodologies, then it doesn't sound like you're using context-driven testing in such a project.

Comment: No, context driven testing means you are choosing techniques, methods, deliverables etc. in the context of the project, you do not to try to apply "best practices". And what I ask is - what about projects where you simply cannot do that because of standards, regulations, restrictions..

Comment: The [Context Driven Testing site](http://context-driven-testing.com/) specifically addresses that concern. Look at the first example project in my answer, above.

Comment: I did read that even on that site but (being a non native speaker) I did not understand what the authors wanted to say - that CDT cannot be applied on the first? That obviously the context is different and testing is not the same in both cases? But it does not answer (maybe just for me) the question whether I could use that or not.

Comment: What they are saying is that your testing process *adapts to your project's concerns.*  That the testing process is going to be different for the first project than it is for the second.  That there is no "one size fits all" process.

Comment: Thanks, also the point is that (similiarly to agile) some projects just wont allow you to do that? E.g. I doubt that medical system controlling the remote-surgery machine (not sure about the name) could be tester with context-driven approach.

Comment: Context-driven Testing says that the medical system will be tested differently than the online game.  It will require different processes and different regulatory oversight.  It will be more rigorous, and probably less agile.  As far as I can tell, Context Driven Testing is not a methodology; it is a philosophy.  You're still going to have to bring some techniques like TDD and Acceptance Testing to the table.  Try to remember that.

Comment: I'm sorry but then how does it help? Everyone knows it will be different but if you read that site, they mention that e.g. context aware is not context driven. That following standards is not context driven and that context driven means looking at the details of the project and then choosing the appropriate techniques etc.

Comment: That's right.  They are saying that *there are no universally best practices,* that the best practices are the ones that most fully meet the needs of your particular project.  I happen to agree with that.  When you make a sweeping statement like "this is the one true way, the one way that everyone should follow under all circumstances," you are automatically wrong.

Comment: Hm, also when I have the choice, I should not try to test online game the same way as I test the medical system (which would be likely possible but too expensive, for example). But when I am just a tester on such a project and cannot choose anything, I cannot be context-driven tester, right?

Comment: *Someone* makes those decisions.  It might not be you.  Those decisions are either context-driven, or they're not.  They are either adapted to the project and its specific concerns, or they're not.  If they are, you can consider it a context-driven process.  Otherwise, no.

Comment: Thanks, so I hope I get it right - if I can, I should always look for the best suitable solution for that project and not things that generally are thought to be good. But if the customer gives me their testing strategy, I cannot do much about that.

Comment: Sounds right to me.